# JQuery - Darken contents of any element i hover over containing a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mousehover

I want to create a hover over event that darkens any element with the class "hover-change".

I don't want to simply change the background color of the triggered element because I want to darken everything (icons, text, background). A solution I have seen online is to overlay another div on top of the selected that is grey/transparent, and when you hover over/out the element, this overlay becomes visible/invisible.

This solution wont work because I dynamically create divs, and I want to attach this functionality to many different elements.

A high level example of what I expect would be nice solution would be:

```
 $(".hover-change").on("mouseover",function(e) {
   $(e.target).css(  /*make entire element darker*/ );

 });

 $(".hover-change").on("mouseout",function(e) {
    $(e.target).css(  /*make entire element normal colour*/ );
 });
```

I can't overlay a "hidden dark transparent pane" over EVERY element because I am dynamically creating the html with handlebars.

Thanks heaps to anyone that can help me out! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't overlay a "hidden dark transparent pane" over EVERY element because I am dynamically creating the html with handlebars.

Actually you can, just do it, *dynamically*.

for example:

```js
$('.item').on("mouseover", function(){
  $(this).append('<div class="overlay"></div>')
})
$('.item').on("mouseout", function(){
  $('.overlay', this).remove();
})
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  position:relative;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
  background-color: rgba(253,253,253,1);
  margin: 2px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align:center;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  text
</div>
<div class="item">
  text
</div>
<div class="item">
  text
</div>
<div class="item">
  text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> This solution wont work because I dynamically create divs

So you may need to delegate the event.
   You can make these changes.

```
 $("body").on("mouseover",'.hover-change',function(e) {
   $(e.target).css(  /*make entire element darker*/ );

 });

 $("body").on("mouseout",'.hover-change',function(e) {
    $(e.target).css(  /*make entire element normal colour*/ );
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("mouseover",".hover-change",function(e) {
    $(e.target).css( /* make entire element darker */ );
});

$(document).on("mouseout",".hover-change",function(e) {
    $(e.target).css( /* make entire element normal colour */ );
});
```

This should work on all elements present in the DOM at the time of execution of this script, and also on any elements added in the future.